# build a better data access layer

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, linq

In order to acces my db and use my stored procedures I made this very simple data access layer (if someone can call this "layer"). I have 8 files where each file looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

public class TasksDBHandler
{
    private static Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DBNAME");

    public static void SetTaskDepreciationData(long taskId, long fieldId, string value)
    {
        DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.P_CUS_TSK_SetTaskDepreciationData");
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@task_id", DbType.Int64, taskId);
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@field_id", DbType.Int64, field);
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@value", DbType.String, value);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    }

    //Many more stored procedures calls
}
```

I want to build a new and better data access layer but I don't know how should it look like. I want the ability to use stored procedures without the need to write static method for each stored procedure, I want better connection menagement and so on/

Is anyone have any clue how to do so?

I am using .Net and SQL SERVER.

Comment: Definitely follow the advice in the answer and use an ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at any of the ORM products out there? There's Linq2Sql, Entity Framework, NHibernate, and others. Unless what you need to do is very basic, you'll probably have better results learning to use an existing framework than trying to write your own.

In an ORM like Entity Framework, you typically don't manage your connection manually, it defines an object (or entity) model from your database and a "context" which is responsible for retrieving the data from your database and mapping it to the correct properties on the classes in your entity model. So you request something from the context, it loads the data necessary to fulfill your request into memory, you work with it like other classes, and then tell the context to save your changes back to the database. There are several ways to interact with your entity model in entity framework, but the example I'll use is Linq2Entities. You write a Linq query, and the context is responsible for turning that into a query against the database **disclaimer: I haven't tried to run this code, it's just meant to serve as an example*

```
using(MyEntitiesContext context = new MyEntitiesContext())
{
    var idleUsers = from u in context.User
                    where u.LoggedIn && u.LastActivity > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30)
                    select u;

    foreach(User u in idleUsers)
    {
        u.Status = UserStatus.Idle;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Obviously there's a lot going on behind the scenes:

- There's the whole object model that gets generated from your database (you select the tables you want to be included in your model, and you can create multiple models in the same project).
- There's the context, which manages the database connection and turns your Linq expression into a database query
- There's the connection string that has to be defined your .config file so Entity Framework knows how to connect to your database

You should be able to find plenty of information on Entity Framework, but the easiest way I've found to learn is to jump in and start trying to do something, and then find answers to questions as they come up. I wouldn't try to use it right away on something highly critical or time sensitive, as there's definitely a learning curve, and you'll learn better ways of working with it once you've experienced some of the pitfalls.

Here's a [link to Microsoft's Entity Framework 4 Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx) which should give you something fairly straightforward to try out. Have fun!

Comment: I wish I had all my 1000 stored procedures converted to linq to entities easily. Right now I have many stored procedures and I have to find a way to write better data access layer.

Comment: If there is a way to use linq2entities of other newer framework and support stored procedures so that I can convert things easily when I'll have the time - it will be the best. I will appriciate any starting point.

Comment: @Naor - I know for sure you can get or create sprocs in EF (Either nab them from a database or generate them to publish later).

Comment: In Entity Framework you should be able to create your entity model from your database and then attach your stored procedures as methods off of the entities. It used to only allow you to attach sprocs as Insert, Update, or Select, but the newer version is more flexible. *disclaimer: I have not actually used that functionality in Entity Framework yet...*

Comment: I will really appriciate an example of dal as it should be. I don't know what to do with the connections and how to start.. I've searched a lot but I cannot focus on something..